# How to compile CodeBlocks MingW in Windows to Ubuntu or Centos

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, codeblocks

Is there a way to compile with `MingW` with `CodeBlocks` in Windows so they can be used in Ubuntu or Centos distros?

I've tried compiling with `GNU GCC` option then got the output file with `.o` extensions under `obj/Release/` folder.

When I run I get this error under my Vagrant Ubuntu machine:

`-bash: ./main.o: cannot execute binary file`

How can I compile it so it runs on my Linux machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical term for what you're trying to accomplish is `cross-compilation`. For that, you need to build a specific cross-compiler using GCC sources. If you still want to keep MinGW, there is a page explaining the steps needed to create a ARM cross-compiler : http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HostedCrossCompilerHOWTO. (you'll have to modify the target)

List of targets supported by GCC :

> armv5te-android-gcc armv5te-linux-rvct armv5te-linux-gcc
>   armv5te-none-rvct
>   armv6-darwin-gcc armv6-linux-rvct armv6-linux-gcc
>   armv6-none-rvct
>   armv7-android-gcc armv7-darwin-gcc armv7-linux-rvct
>   armv7-linux-gcc armv7-none-rvct
>   mips32-linux-gcc
>   ppc32-darwin8-gcc ppc32-darwin9-gcc ppc32-linux-gcc
>   ppc64-darwin8-gcc ppc64-darwin9-gcc ppc64-linux-gcc
>   sparc-solaris-gcc
>   x86-android-gcc x86-darwin8-gcc x86-darwin8-icc
>   x86-darwin9-gcc x86-darwin9-icc x86-darwin10-gcc
>   x86-darwin11-gcc x86-darwin12-gcc x86-linux-gcc
>   x86-linux-icc x86-os2-gcc x86-solaris-gcc
>   x86-win32-gcc x86-win32-vs7 x86-win32-vs8
>   x86-win32-vs9
>   x86_64-darwin9-gcc x86_64-darwin10-gcc x86_64-darwin11-gcc
>   x86_64-darwin12-gcc x86_64-linux-gcc x86_64-linux-icc
>   x86_64-solaris-gcc x86_64-win64-gcc x86_64-win64-vs8
>   x86_64-win64-vs9
>   universal-darwin8-gcc universal-darwin9-gcc universal-darwin10-gcc
>   universal-darwin11-gcc universal-darwin12-gcc
>   generic-gnu

There is only one big caveat : since Windows is not POSIX compliant, I don't think you can use `signals` or `pthreads`.

Finally, brace yourself because it's a tedious task to build a cx-compiler (lots of obscure bugs). That's why profesionnal devs pays $$$ for "plug'n'play" solutions.

EDIT : [this MXE project](http://mxe.cc/) can be useful to you

Comment: Does it mean if I compile in Ubuntu 12.04 desktop using CodeBlocks Ubuntu version I should be able to run on Linux servers without any problems? Maybe I should compile this under Ubuntu instead?

Comment: absolutely ! Native dev is so much easier than xdev. However, centOS is a bit different from Ubuntu, so you'll have to repackage your app : http://askubuntu.com/questions/165643/are-centos-programs-compatible-with-ubuntu

Comment: OK. I've decided to use my docker containers to compile them under CentOS 6.5 with Boost and GNU g++ installed. Question is, how do I compile multiple files including header files into something that is production ready machine code files? Are they multiple binaries or one? Sorry it's my first time compiling for production use